# How can I get count from joined query - criteria builder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-criteria

I have a Entity Policy

```
public class Policy extends BaseEntity {


private Long id;
private String policyNumber;
......
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy(value = "id")
@JoinColumn(name = "policyID")
@Where(clause = "type = 'POLICY_INFO'")
private Set<AssignedUser> assignUsers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I'm trying to get policies who are assigned to specific user. I'm using criteria builder for that and my function looks like this:

```
   public PaginationResult getFilteredData(List<FilterConstraint> filters, Class className) {
    if (filters.get(0).getCount() == 0) {
        filters.get(0).setCount(50);
    }

    try {


        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQueryMain = builder.createQuery(className);
        Root<?> root = criteriaQueryMain.from(className);

        Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();

        List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FilterConstraint constraint : filters) {
            switch (constraint.getOperator()) {
                case IN:
                    LocalDate inDate = new LocalDate();
                    Date maxRange = inDate.plusDays(Integer.parseInt(constraint.getValues().getMinValue())).toDate();
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), inDate.toDate(), maxRange));
                    break;
                case RANGE:
                    LocalDate rangeDate = new LocalDate();
                    Date minDate = rangeDate.plusDays(Integer.parseInt(constraint.getValues().getMinValue())).toDate();
                    Date maxDate = rangeDate.plusDays(Integer.parseInt(constraint.getValues().getMaxValue())).toDate();
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), minDate, maxDate));
                    break;
                case AFTER:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case BEFORE:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.lessThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case BETWEEN:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.DATE) {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate(), constraint.getValues().getEndDate()));
                    } else if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.INTEGER) {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), Integer.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getMinValue()), Integer.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getMaxValue())));
                    } else {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getMinValue(), constraint.getValues().getMaxValue()));
                    }
                    break;
                case EMPTY:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.isNull(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                    break;
                case EQUALS:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.ENUM) {

                        if (constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().size() > 1) {

                            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {

                                for (Field f : className.getDeclaredFields()) {
                                    if (f.getName().equals(constraint.getField().getValue())) {
                                        System.out.println("T");
                                        Class<?> clz = f.getType();
                                        Object[] consts = clz.getEnumConstants();
                                        Root<?> finalEqualsRoot = root;
                                        Arrays.stream(consts)
                                                .filter(e -> e.toString().equals(enumValue.getValue()))
                                                .forEach(e -> predicates.add(builder.equal(finalEqualsRoot.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), e)));
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            predicate = builder.and(builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
                            break;
                        }

                        predicate = builder.equal(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), getObjectBySelectedField(className, constraint));
                        break;
                    }
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.BOOLEAN) {
                        if (Boolean.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getValue()))
                            predicate = builder.and(builder.isTrue(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                        else predicate = builder.and(builder.isFalse(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                        break;
                    }
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    /*predicate = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()).get("id"), constraint.getValues().getValue()));*/
                    break;
                case NOT_EQUALS:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.ENUM) {

                        if (constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().size() > 1) {

                            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {

                                for (Field f : className.getDeclaredFields()) {
                                    if (f.getName().equals(constraint.getField().getValue())) {
                                        System.out.println("T");
                                        Class<?> clz = f.getType();
                                        Object[] consts = clz.getEnumConstants();
                                        Root<?> finalNotEqualsRoot = root;
                                        Arrays.stream(consts)
                                                .filter(e -> e.toString().equals(enumValue.getValue()))
                                                .forEach(e -> predicates.add(builder.notEqual(finalNotEqualsRoot.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), e)));
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            predicate = builder.and(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
                            break;
                        }

                        predicate = builder.notEqual(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), getObjectBySelectedField(className, constraint));
                        break;
                    }
                    if (constraint.getValues().getValue() != null)
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.and(builder.notEqual(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue())));
                    else
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.and(builder.notEqual(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate())));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.lessThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    break;
                case MORE_THAN:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    break;
                case NOT_EMPTY:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.isNotNull(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                    break;
                case ON:
                    predicate = builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), DateUtils.getFirstSecondOfDate(constraint.getValues().getStartDate()), DateUtils.getLastSecondOfDate(constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case STARTS_WITH:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.like(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue() + "%"));
                    break;
                case TODAY:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), DateUtils.getFirstSecondOfDate(new Date()), DateUtils.getLastSecondOfDate(new Date())));
                    break;
                case THIS_WEEK:
                    LocalDate thisWeekDate = new LocalDate();
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), thisWeekDate.minusDays(7).toDate(), thisWeekDate.toDate()));
                    break;
                case THIS_MONTH:
                    LocalDate thisMonthDate = new LocalDate();
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), thisMonthDate.minusDays(thisMonthDate.getDayOfMonth() - 1).toDate(), thisMonthDate.toDate()));
                    break;
                case THIS_YEAR:
                    LocalDate thisYearDate = new LocalDate();
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), thisYearDate.minusYears(1).toDate(), thisYearDate.toDate()));
                    break;
                case LAST_DAYS:
                    LocalDate last_DaysDate = new LocalDate();
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), last_DaysDate.minusDays(Integer.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getValue())).toDate(), last_DaysDate.toDate()));
                    break;
            }
            if (!predicateList.contains(predicate)) {
                predicateList.add(predicate);
            }
        }


        if (className.equals(Policy.class)) {
            Long userID = 555L;
            Join assignUsers = root.join("assignUsers");
            predicate = builder.equal(assignUsers.get("assignedUserId"), userID);
            predicateList.add(predicate);
        }

        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        cq.select(builder.count(cq.from(className)));
        em.createQuery(cq);

        cq.where(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        Long count = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();

        criteriaQueryMain.where(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        predicateList.clear();



        TypedQuery<?> q = em.createQuery(criteriaQueryMain);
        q.setMaxResults(filters.get(0).getCount());
        int firstResult = filters.get(0).getPage() * filters.get(0).getCount() - filters.get(0).getCount();
        q.setFirstResult(firstResult);

        PaginationResult result = new PaginationResult();
        result.setData(q.getResultList());
        result.setMaxResults(count);

        System.out.println(result.getData().size());

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I try to run int I receive such error message:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.assignedUserId' [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.clphub.model.policy.Policy as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.id>100L ) and ( generatedAlias1.assignedUserId=555L )]
```

I tried a lot of combinations but can't get read of this error message. Problem occurs on count section of code. If I comment the count query - I get the data correctly.

Can someone tell me what is the problem? what I'm doing wrong?

I use JPA, Hibernate, Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

In your count, try to put the root

```
cq.select(builder.count(root));
```

It seems, by the exception, that the where clause is trying to get a variable that is not in "from".

Comment: Error occurred validating the Criteria, java.lang.NullPointerException -- I receive this error

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am curious now.